# Bad performance in UIImageView when displaying shadows

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimageview, quartz-graphics

I have got a scroll view displaying images. Its "clip subviews" setting is off, so images to the left and right are displayed as well. If I'm adding shadows to the image views like below (using QuartzCore), the scrolling performance is severly degraded.

```
imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
imageView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0;
imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9;
```

Is there a way to add shadows to image views in a better-perfoming way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your shadow settings.

```
imageView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageView.bounds].CGPath;
```

May be this will help in smoother scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Performance is a LOT better, but it also changes the appearance of the shadow. I have to change the bezier rect in order to get about the same effect.

Comment: Exactly! bezier rect can be changed to get any desired effect!